# Linuxbrew installation issue

Tags: ruby, git, bash, ubuntu

I just installed linuxbrew with

> git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew

Then I checked the environment variables and

> $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
>   bash: /home/danilo/.linuxbrew/lib64/pkgconfig:/home/danilo/.linuxbrew/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:: **No such file or directory**

It seems that not everything went in the right place. In fact, I having problem with several package installation

> Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/dupes/unzip" (dependency of milaboratory/all/mixcr)
>   ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
>   Error: No similarly named formulae found.
>   ==> Searching taps...
>   Error: No formulae found in taps.

How is it possible?

(I am using Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: That repository you linked to says it is deprecated in favor of https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew Why not use that?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. GoodLuck